# uploading file - unable to find file field :input

Tags: html, file-upload, capybara, selector, visible

I have html looking like this:

```
<div id="promocodesUpload">
<div class="qq-uploader">
   <div class="qq-upload-drop-area" style="display: none;">
      <span>Drop </span>
   </div>
   <a class="qq-upload-button btn" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; direction: ltr;">Upload
       <input type="file" name="file" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; 
       top: 0px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 118px; margin: 0px; 
       padding: 0px; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0;">
   </a>
   <ul class="qq-upload-list"></ul>
</div>
</div>
```

And I need to upload file using capybara automated tests:

I have tried many ways but all I get is Unable to find file field :input or Element not found  and so on...

```
$code_id = '//*contains(@id,"promocodesUpload")]/div/a[contains(., "Upload")]'
$code_path = 'C:\\promotion_codes.txt'

  within(:xpath, $code_id)do
    attach_file(:input, $code_path)
  end
```

I also tried with

```
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false and 
attach_file(:input, $code_path, :visible =false)
```

some otpions that I found here. but still nothing.... easier node selectors do not work at all like
 `//*[@id="promocodesUpload"]/div/a/input` and so on.... I don't know what to do...

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen qq-upload in the past and that specific javascript library for uploading files just doesn't work with selenium-webdriver.  You may have to look into integrating a tool like AutoIT into your script if you happen to be on Windows.

It's unfortunate but the drag and drop functionality just seems to be problematic with what selenium-webdriver is capable of doing.  Even being able to hit the 'browse' button (if you can actually succeed in doing that) causes problems since that will open a dialog box outside the scope of what a browser can do.

Comment: OK, thank you for your answer. I'll try something else then :)